# How can we check case sensitivity for strings in Apex?

Tags: apex

I need to check the case sensitivity of strings in apex:

```
String a = 'ABC';
String b = 'abc';
```

I need to check for the above string. Please give some ideas.

Comment: do you want to compare both string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String a = 'abc';
String b = 'ABC';
System.debug(a.equals(b));  //false
System.debug(a.equalsignorecase(b));  //true
```

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

compareTo(secondString)

Compares two strings lexicographically, based on the Unicode value of each character in the Strings.
Signature

public Integer compareTo(String secondString)

Parameters

secondString
Type: String
Return Value

Type: Integer

Usage

The result is:

A negative Integer if the String that called the method lexicographically precedes secondString
A positive Integer if the String that called the method lexicographically follows compsecondStringString
Zero if the Strings are equal
If there is no index position at which the Strings differ, then the shorter String lexicographically precedes the longer String.

Note that this method returns 0 whenever the equals method returns true.

```
String a= 'ABC'; 
String b = 'abc';

Integer result = a.compareTo(b);
System.debug(':::'+result);
```

Comment: thanks devendra. Although i could not use what you proposed , i learned something from the above info :)